# Can I use an index signature to create an array of descriptions for an enum?

Tags: typescript, enums, index-signature

Suppose I have the following enum:

```
export enum ApiRole {
    User = 1,
    SuperUser = 2,
    Restricted = 3,
}
```

Is there a way for me to easily create an array that I can use these enum values to index that will return a string value I can use as a description?

I have tried this:

```
export const ApiRoleDescriptions: {[role: number]: string} = {
    1: 'Normal User',
    2: 'Super User',
    3: 'Restricted',
}
```

But this method requires me to manually set the numeric values of each enum value which is a bit of a maintainability problem.

At the end of the day I'd like to be able to write something like `ApiRoleDescriptions[ApiRole.User]` directly somewhere else in my code.

EDIT: Looks like the answer to my question at the time of writing is no - at least until [this PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/26797) is merged in to typescript, which currently has a milestone of 3.3/3.4. However, I am still looking for some sort of method to accomplish this in the meantime.

Comment: "this method requires me to manually set the numeric values of each enum value" --- if not manually how else would TS know `ApiRole.User` is a `Normal User`?

Comment: I'd like to be able to use the enum values with their names in the definition of the indexer. So something like `export const ApiRoleDescriptions: {[role: ApiRole]: string} = { ApiRole.User: 'Normal User', }` etc.

Comment: Basically, I just think it's weird that an index signature requires a `string` or `number` value, and an enum can be either `string` or `number` valued, but it still can't be used in an index signature.

Comment: `const ApiRoleDescriptions: {[k in ApiRole]: string} = {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would declare it like this:

```
export const ApiRoleDescriptions: {[k in ApiRole]: string} = {
    1: 'Normal User',
    2: 'Super User',
    [ApiRole.Restricted]: 'Restricted',
}
```

`in ApiRole` would ensure that all keys are of known enum values and that all values are assigned.

References:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Comment: This is almost what I want, in that it is pulling the values from `ApiRole`, but it still requires me to define them in format `'1': 'Normal User'` instead of `ApiRole.User: 'Normal User'`